# Azure - How is the Data from the RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances Generated?

Tags: azure, azure-role-environment

I have a question, some of my code is often iterating over the 
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances collection.

How is this data collected?  Is it refreshed frequently? is it always live data?

I am still working in the developer emulated environment so i'm not able to deduce this so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the library fetched this data but I assume it's reading from C:\Config... on the instances (remote desktop into a server and go wild ;-)). If that assumption is correct, the values will be retrieved from the system only once for every RoleEnvironmentChanging event, that is: at startup and when config/topology changes. But like I said: those are assumptions.

Comment: I can confirm that the data is cached (that I am sure of).  However, like maartenba, I don't know how often it is updated or if it is using the xml files or talking to the fabric agent.  I suspect that maartenba is correct however if I had to guess as well.  Perhaps smarx will confirm the exact method it uses to update the cache.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the exact mechanism, but it *is* proactively updated (when something changes), so this data should be very up to date.

Comment: Thanks - I think that answers the question and addresses any concerns - it is correct and it is not expensive